# Want to use VBA to paste monthly totals next to the corresponding month

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a time card in excel and I want to let the user type their monthly hours, and then at the end of the month run the macro to have the hours collect next to the month to accumulate a yearly total.

I have the current month in cell C5 (as the first of the month ex 8/1/2023), the total number of hours in D36, and the months (1/1/2023-12/1/2023) listed from cell M27-M38. I want the number of hours to paste from D36 into cell N27:N38 next to the month that is in cell C5 (example, if C5 is 8/1/2023 I want it to paste in Col N right next to where 8/1/2023 is in Col M.

Can anyone help me write this?

Answer (score 0):

Excel formula is a good option to get your expected result.

- Apply formula `=IF(M27=$C$5,$D$36,"")` to cell N27
- Filling the formula down through cell N38, `123` will show on cell N34

[image]

---

To accomplish this in VBA, you can try:

```
Sub CopyData()
    With Range("C5")
        If VBA.IsDate(.Value) Then
            Range("N26").Offset(VBA.Month(.Value)).Value = Range("D36").Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```